# Selector usage when styling nav created by unordered lists

Tags: html, css

The questions below pertain to sample HTML / CSS code below:

```css
ul {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
}
li {
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Home</li>
  <li>Portfolio</li>
</ul>
```

1. When choosing to format and style a navigation menu that was created using an unordered list, what is the difference of using ul selector to target the lists versus targeting the li selector directly?
2. Is there an appropriate time when I should only use ul selector instead of li, and vice versa? In other words, are there properties that only work on the ul level. And on the li level?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there are things you simply **cannot do** selecting `ul` (I mean with pure CSS solutions, omitting preprocessors):

```
li { color: blue; }
li:first-child, li:last-child { color: red }
```

and so on with [:pseudo-classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-classes).

Main point in selecting whole container and targeting nested elements is just **much less** writing. Compare:

```
<ul>
  <li class="my-superior-class-name"
  <li class="my-superior-class-name">A</li>
  <li class="my-superior-class-name">A</li>
  <li class="my-superior-class-name">A</li>
  <li class="my-superior-class-name">A</li>
  <li class="my-superior-class-name">A</li>
  <li class="my-superior-class-name">A</li>
  <li class="my-superior-class-name">A</li>
</ul>
```

with:

```
<ul class="my-superior-class-name">
  <li>A</li>
  <li>A</li>
  <li>A</li>
  <li>A</li>
  <li>A</li>
  <li>A</li>
  <li>A</li>
</ul>
```

Main difference in targeting `ul` and `li` with your CSS styles is that **targeting deeper nested elements has bigger priority**.

Unorderd list's default styles are:

```
ul { 
  list-style-type: disc; 
  list-style-position: inside; 
}
```

So this are kind of properties which *work only on `ul` lvl*. But consider situation, when you set `padding` on the `ul`: Does every single `ul` child gets the same padding? There comes [inheritance](https://www.w3.org/wiki/Inheritance_and_cascade).

Overall, one advice: just don't overcomplicate it and use what you feel is simplest to understand and come back to for you.

Answer (score 0):

Not every property is inherited implicitly, in fact in OP's code there's proof. The property `display:inline-block` is applied to `<ul>` yet the `<li>` will not inherit the `display:inline-block` from `<ul>` unless it does so explicitly by using `display:inherit` on the `<li>` (Might as well use `display: inline-block` on the `<li>` anyways since both options take the same effort to write.)

There are circumstances in which it would behoove us to target a `<ul>` over it's `<li>` such as the properties that are inherited implicitly: `font-size`, `color`, `visibility` etc.

#### SNIPPET

```css
ul {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
}
li {
  color: #000;
}
ul:last-of-type {
  display: block;
}
ul:last-of-type li {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<h5><mark><code>ul { display:inline-block; }</code></mark></h5>
<ul>
  <li>Home</li>
  <li>Portfolio</li>
</ul>
<h5><mark><code>li { display:inline-block; }</code></mark></h5>
<ul>
  <li>Home</li>
  <li>Portfolio</li>
</ul>
```